# HDRI environment image not showing in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

So i have a HDRI environment set up but when i render it in cycles i get just a blank white background, and to be honest it doesnt even look like the same lighting?[image]
Using 2.8

Comment: Are you sure one of your many hidden objects isn't obscuring the hdri in your final render? when you hide the object with h or in the outliner, it will only be hidden in the viewport, not the render.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you :-)